# sum of roots of Quadratic equations within modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\left|ax^2+bx+c\right|\leq \left|x^2-2x+3\right|\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}$ denote the sum of all $4$ roots of $2$ quadratic

within modulus, Then $\mathbb{S} = $

$\underline{\bf{My \;\; Try}}$:: $\left|ax^2+bx+c\right|\leq \left|x^2-2x+3\right|\Rightarrow \left|ax^2+bx+c\right|^2\leq \left|x^2-2x+3\right|^2$

So $\left(ax^2+bx+c\right)^2\leq \left(x^2-2x+3\right)^2$

So $-(x^2-2x+3)\leq ax^2+bx+c\leq (x^2-2x+3)$

Now How can I proceed further, please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The roots of $x^2-2x+3$ must also be roots of $ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: If $x^2-2x+3=0$ at some $x$, then you get $|ax^2+bx+c| \leqslant 0$, i.e. $ax^2+bx+c=0$ at that point.